# Fragment/Activity Lifecycles and Orientation Change

Tags: android, android-fragments, orientation-changes

Fragments are funny things but, so I thought, once you know their quirks they're an invaluable tool for writing good code across multiple devices.

However, while fixing an orientation change bug I've run up against a wall. For my fragment to work it needs access to a View which belongs to it's containing Activity leading me on a merry chase trying to find how the Activity & Fragment lifecycles interact.

I'm adding a fragment to my Activities view in it's `onCreate()` method:

```
// Only add a fragment once, as after it's been added it cannot be replaced (Even though there is a .replace() method. Which is a massive gaping hole in fragments as a technology if you ask me)
if(savedInstanceState == null) {
    MainMenuFragment menu= new MainMenuFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();   
    transaction.replace(R.id.menuFrame, menu);  
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Leading to this Activity->Fragment Lifecycle:

```
01-04 15:17:27.226: W/SinglePaneActivity 0:   onCreate()
01-04 15:17:27.378: W/MainMenuFragment   0:   onAttach() to SinglePaneActivity 0
01-04 15:17:27.378: W/MainMenuFragment   0:   onCreate()
01-04 15:17:27.453: W/MainMenuFragment   0:   onActivityCreated()
01-04 15:17:27.476: W/MainMenuFragment   0:   onStart()
01-04 15:17:27.476: W/SinglePaneActivity 0:   onStart()
01-04 15:17:27.476: W/SinglePaneActivity 0:   onResume()
01-04 15:17:27.476: W/MainMenuFragment   0:   onResume()
```

An orientation change however highlights that this isn't usually the case, A fragments `onCreate()` method isn't called after it's parent Activities `onCreate()`. Infact, the first lifecycle call of a Fragment's `onAttach()` occurs before the Activity has even been created (`null` is passed as an argument):

```
01-04 15:10:49.589: W/MainMenuFragment   0:   onPause()
01-04 15:10:49.589: W/SinglePaneActivity 0:   onPause()
01-04 15:10:49.589: W/MainMenuFragment   0:   onStop()
01-04 15:10:49.589: W/SinglePaneActivity 0:   onStop()
01-04 15:10:49.589: W/MainMenuFragment   0:   onDestroyView()
01-04 15:10:49.589: W/MainMenuFragment   0:   onDestroy()
01-04 15:10:49.589: W/MainMenuFragment   0:   onDetach()
01-04 15:10:49.609: W/SinglePaneActivity 0:   onDestroy()
01-04 15:10:49.617: W/MainMenuFragment   1:   onAttach() to null
01-04 15:10:49.617: W/MainMenuFragment   1:   onCreate()
01-04 15:10:49.617: W/SinglePaneActivity 1:   onCreate()
01-04 15:10:49.890: W/MainMenuFragment   1:   onActivityCreated()
01-04 15:10:49.917: W/MainMenuFragment   1:   onStart()
01-04 15:10:49.917: W/SinglePaneActivity 1:   onStart()
01-04 15:10:49.921: W/SinglePaneActivity 1:   onResume()
01-04 15:10:49.921: W/MainMenuFragment   1:   onResume()
```

I have absolutely no idea why this is occuring. Could anyone shed any light on why `Fragment.onAttach()` is being called before it's containing Activity has been created?

Fragments I've got which don't need access to their containing activity (until UI interaction) work as expected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Argh,

```
01-04 15:46:23.175: W/MainMenuFragment   0: onAttach() to SinglePaneActivity 0
01-04 15:46:23.179: W/MainMenuFragment   0: onCreate()
01-04 15:46:23.246: W/MainMenuFragment   0: onActivityCreated() with Activity SinglePaneActivity 0
01-04 15:46:23.269: W/MainMenuFragment   0: onStart()
01-04 15:46:23.269: W/SinglePaneActivity 0: onStart()
```

Why the heck there is an `onAttach()` method I have no idea. Especially since "attach" happens before there is an Activity.

The method I needed was of course, `onActivityCreated()` which happens as the final call in the "Creation" set of [Fragment lifecycle events](http://developer.android.com/images/fragment_lifecycle.png).